# Disable applying table sorter for certain tbody for a table having multiple tbody's

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have two different tbody's within the same table. I want the table sorter only on the first tbody. Is there a way to skip using tablesorter for the second tbody alone???

```
<table>
<tbody id="1"></tbody>  /* Apply table sorter for this tbody */
<tbody id="2"></tbody>  /* Don't Apply table sorter for this tbody*/
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/index.html) which does support [sorting multiple tbodies](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-multiple-tbodies.html). The original plugin only sorts the first tbody.

If you want tablesorter to ignore any tbody, just add the class name `tablesorter-infoOnly` to the tbody. This class name is set by the [`cssInfoBlock` option](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/index.html#cssinfoblock).

Just to note, tablesorter won't work on the HTML you shared above unless the table contains a `thead`.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the second tbody as another table, and use CSS to make them look like one table.

```
<table>/* Apply table sorter for this table */
<tbody id="1"></tbody>  
</table>

<table>/* Don't Apply table sorter for this table*/
<tbody id="2"></tbody>  
</table>
```